# Check if Mix Full-Width and Half Width Japanese Characters JavaScript

Tags: javascript, cjk

Can anyone suggest how to check if the string is composed of a mix of full-width and half-width Japanese characters in JavaScript?

Mix Characters is composed of

1. Kana characters
2. Numbers
3. Special Characters
4. Letters

Example:

```
Ａａ！bb123ｻﾝﾌﾟﾙ
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function checkCharacterWidth(input) {
  var hasFullWidth = false;
  var hasHalfWidth = false;

  for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    var charCode = input.charCodeAt(i);
    if (
      (charCode >= 0x0020 && charCode <= 0x007E) || // Half-width characters
      (charCode >= 0xFF61 && charCode <= 0xFF9F) || // Half-width Katakana
      (charCode >= 0xFFA0 && charCode <= 0xFFDC) || // Full-width Roman characters and half-width voiced sound marks
      (charCode >= 0xFFE8 && charCode <= 0xFFEE)    // Half-width punctuation marks and symbols
    ) {
      hasHalfWidth = true;
    } else {
      hasFullWidth = true;
    }

    if (hasFullWidth && hasHalfWidth) {
      return true;
    }
  }

  return false;
}

// Example usage:
var userInput = prompt('Enter your input:');
var hasMixedWidth = checkCharacterWidth(userInput);
console.log('Has mixed width:', hasMixedWidth);
```

Comment: I don't think this works.  Try it on `ｻ`, `サ`, and `ｻサ`.  Only the last one is a mix.  But your code also claims that `サ` is a mix.

Comment: the textbox requires 10 characters, but i still edit it can you confirm?

Comment: This is currently a _code-only_ answer. It could be improved by explaining the approach.  Especially since there seems to be an incongruity that you detect what may be `Full-width Roman characters` (as per your comment) and set the flag `hasHalfWidth = true` as a result.